# apply.pd.to_date_Time. apply being unmapped/ dealing with NaT

Tags: python, pandas

I'm a bit confused on an issue I have been having with my code test data below, as well as explanation.

```
test = {"Med to Ind Date": ['', '', 1402531200000000000, '', 1402876800000000000], 
        "Med to Ind Indicator": ['', '', 'Y', '', 'Y']}
test = pd.DataFrame(test)
date_fields = ["Med to Ind Date"]
test.loc[:, date_fields] = test.loc[:, date_fields].apply(pd.to_datetime)
```

So when you run the above code you will see that all the blank time fields are mapped to NaT. Which is fine, however it is interrupting my code below:

```
if "Med to Ind Indicator" in test.columns:
    test["Med to Ind Indicator"] = np.where(test["Med to Ind Date"] != '', "Yes", '')
```

The code above looks at the Med to Ind Date field, and if it isn't blank it maps the column Med to Ind Indicator to Yes.
The work around I had was trying to replace pd.NaT with "" which worked, but it in turn undid my date_time transformation, and returned it to the original form.  Can you guys recommend an alternative? Also, how exactly does pandas view the NaT field?

Comment: `test[date_fields] = test.loc[:, date_fields].apply(pd.to_datetime, unit='ns', errors='coerce')` - this should answer your first question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `isnull()` (or `notnull()`) to test for `NaT`:

```
np.where(test["Med to Ind Date"].isnull(), '', "Yes")
```

Resulting output of `test`:

```
       Med to Ind Date Med to Ind Indicator
0                 None                     
1                 None                     
2  1402531200000000000                  Yes
3                 None                     
4  1402876800000000000                  Yes
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you. That answers my second question as well. So Pandas treats null time values as NaT.